# searching issues in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels',:search=>params[:search],method: :post do %>
<div id="box" style="width: 400px;margin-left: 33%">
<%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => 'search-box', :required => true,:placeholder=>'Type Your City Name(Bhubaneswar,Cuttack)'%>
</div>

<%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch',class: "btnSearch",:method=>'post'%>

</div>
<%end%>
```

In Controller:

`def index`

`@hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%").includes(:offers)`

In routes i have:

`get 'hotels/index'`

`match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:option)',:via=>[:get,:post]`

After clicking on the search button i am getting in my logs:

`Started POST "/hotels/index?method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-08 12:32:07 +0530`
`Processing by HotelsController#index as HTML`

After clicking on the search button, its working fine but when i am refreshing the page `/hotels/index?method=post`, the filtering value(params[:search]) gets lost and the page showing me all the hotels present in the database table.Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form_tag` declaration should be:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels', :action => 'index' do %>

<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= form_tag hotels_path do %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: no there is no action search,please see the above controller code i have edited

Answer (score 0):

Your form should look like:

```
<%= form_tag hotels_path do %>
  <div id="box" style="width: 400px;margin-left: 33%">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => 'search-box', :required => true,:placeholder=>'Type Your City Name(Bhubaneswar,Cuttack)'%>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>'btnsearch',class: "btnSearch",:method=>'post'%>
<%end%>
```

On first request to your home controller you may need all hotels. So your controller should be:

```
def index 
  if params[:search].present? ? @hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search]}%").includes(:offers) : Hotel.includes(:offers) 
end
```

Comment: `<%= form_tag hotels_path do %>` this gives me error` thats why i am using <%= form_tag :controller => 'hotels', :action => 'index' do %>`....if i post `:search` value in the url then problem gets solved....but how do i add it like `http://localhost:3000/hotels/index?search=delhi`.

Comment: Have you tried controller code also. What is the error you are facing? Because in my controller code I have handled params blank condition also. also post your routes file here because if you use default routing you won't have ant index action with type POST.

Comment: Try change `get 'hotels/index'` to `resources :hotels` and your form will work. As there will be no `hotels_path` if you use `get 'hotels/index'` now your url should look like `/hotels` instead of `/hotles/index` try type `/hotels` in your url.. See this also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I have tried `resources :hotels` which gives me error like `The action 'create' could not be found for HotelsController`....i dont want to use `create action`....is there any other way

Comment: now i have created the `create view file` but when i am clicking on the search it takes me to the create page instead of index

Answer (score 0):

For the record `text_field_tag` takes a string and not a symbol http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag .  And since you're using index as your controller I suggest you use the GET mthod `method: :get`.  Google's search uses the GET method for search, that is why you see the query in the url

```
<%= form_tag hotels_path, method: :get do %>
  <div id="box" style="width: 400px;margin-left: 33%">
    <%= text_field_tag 'hotels[search]', nil, class: 'search-box', required: true, placeholder: 'Type Your City Name(Bhubaneswar,Cuttack)' %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: 'btnsearch', class: "btnSearch" %>
<% end %>
```

You don't need to set the method in the submit button, that's handled in the `form_tag` or `form_for`.

And for Rails 4 you're going to want to have strong_params so you should have a private method for that:

```
private
def hotels_params
  params.require(:hotel).permit(:search)
end
```

Then in your controller you can change the search param to:

```
def index
  @hotels= Hotel.where('hotel_location LIKE ?',"%#{hotels_params[:search]}%").includes(:offers)
```

Although I don't like having your model logic in the controller.  I believe you should move it to your Model itself.  There's plenty of online documentation about that.  It would be much nicer to do a `@hotels = Hotel.similar_to(hotels_params['search'])` By it calling your own query method in the model named `similar_to`.

Also you should keep in mind there won't always be a search param when you view the index.  You can `hotels_params.has_key? 'search'` or set and **or equals** setting on @hotels.

```
@hotels = Hotel.similar_to(hotels_params['search']) ||= [Hotel.new]
```